# Mose clicks not registering in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

This is not a coding question, this is a problem I frequently encounter in the Visual Studio IDE. My mouse clicks are often ignored if I work fast. Usually it happens when I click on a variable name, the studio starts loading a tooltip or a highlighter for that variable and I immediately click on another variable or any other place in the editor window - the click will be ignored. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

This started happening around 2 years ago, don't remember exactly when, but it was right after a new version of the Studio was released.

Comment: VS 2015 and VS 2017 are sluggish as hell for me too. I can't even type for several seconds every few minutes.